# Remove pauses greater than x from pcap file

Tags: tcpdump, wireshark

I've captured udp traffic to a pcap file. When replaying with `tcpreplay-edit`, I'd like to shorten all pauses (where there is no udp traffic at all) to `x seconds` max. `tcpreplay-edit` only has a global speed multiplier.

Is there any automated way to do this? Ideally without resorting to guis like `wireshark`, but any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still curious if there is a way, but in the meantime I found a workaround for the case at hand by using one of the following parameters of `tcpreplay-edit`:

> -p number, --pps=number **Replay packets at a given packets/sec.**
>
> -M string, --mbps=string **Replay packets at a given Mbps.**
>
> -t, --topspeed **Replay packets as fast as possible.**

Answer (score 0):

With a script? Sure. Without a script? Well, kinda.

You can use editcap's -S (strict time adjustment) option with a negative value to adjust the time of all packets to the previous packet's timestamp plus the -S value. A positive value for -S will only adjust the timestamp if the packet's time is before the previous packet's timestamp. For this use case, you wanna adjust them all.

So if you have 3 packets with timestamps like:

```
23:00:00.100
23:01:00.345
23:05:00.678
```

And you ran editcap on the pcap file with -S -0.001, you'd get:

```
23:00:00.100
23:00:00.101
23:00:00.102
```

Hopefully that makes sense and helps you out.

http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html

Comment: Thanks karyhead. Your suggestion will not only remove long pauses between 2 packets, it will change the timestamps of all packages. The effect of doing this and then tcp-replaying is the same as simply running `tcpreplay-edit --pps 1000`. In other words, no need to run an extra command, unless of course you want to normalize your pcap timestamps once'n'for all.